# How to disable strict_raw_type and inference_failure_on_function_return_type from analysis_option.yaml on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, linter

I have a lot of warnings with `strict_raw_type` and `inference_failure_on_function_return_type` from the dart analyzer.

I tried to pass to the `analysis_option.yaml` the rules:

```
linter:
  rules:
    strict_raw_type: false
    inference_failure_on_function_return_type: false
```

But it says that are not recognized as lint rules.

How can I disable these rules?

I use `very_good_analysis` package for lints.

Comment: Have you considered fixing your code instead?  In my experience, false positives from `strict_raw_types` are not common.  It's also very uncommon to disable errors (such as `inference_failure_on_function_return_type`) which are distinct from lints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

I added under `analyzer`:

```
  language:
    strict-raw-types: false
```

And also I added some error rules under `analyzer`:

```
  errors:
    inference_failure_on_function_return_type: ignore
    inference_failure_on_untyped_parameter: ignore
    inference_failure_on_instance_creation: ignore
    inference_failure_on_function_invocation: ignore
```